# How to do code coverage for localStorage and subscribe function item in angular test case

Tags: unit-testing, angular7

Im creating test case for Angular 7 project. In that i can't able to do code coverage for localStorage and subscribe and its err function.

//Statement not covered

```
localStorage.setItem('email', email);
```

//Function not covered

```
this.valService.checkVal(email,pwd).subscribe((data : any)=>{
  },
  (err : HttpErrorResponse)=>{
    this.isLoginError = true;
  });
```